# R: row.names and data manipulation / export

Tags: r, export, dataframe

I am having some issues understanding what `row.names` is and how it works. And, how I can get my data to do stuff the `row.names` allows one to do.

For example, I am creating some clusters with the code below (my data).  I want to export the results which is what the `sapply` line does, but only to the screen for now.  The first column (path_country) of my data frame are country names and the other columns are other variables (integers).  I don't see an easy way to export these clusters to a table or list of countries and their group membership.

I tried to make a dummy example using example data sets in R.  For example, `mtcars`, it was then that I noticed the first column was denoted as `row.names`.  With `mtcars` I can create clusters, `cutree` to the specified number of groups and then save as a data frame. With this approach I have the 'car names' in the first column and the group number in the second column (more or less, could be cleaned up to look nicer, but is essentially what I am after), which is what I would like to happen with my data.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

```
# my data
path_country <- read.csv("C:/path_country.csv")
patho <- subset(path_country, select=c(2:188))
patho.d <- dist(patho)

patho.hclust <- hclust(patho.d)
patho.hclust.groups11 = cutree(patho.hclust,11)
sapply(unique(patho.hclust.groups11),function(g)path_country$Country[patho.hclust.groups11 == g])

# mtcars data
car.d <- dist(mtcars)
car.h <- hclust(car.d)
car.h.11 <- cutree(car.h, 11)
nice_result <- as.data.frame(car.h.11)
write.table(nice_result, "test.txt", sep="\t")
```

Comment: `row.names` are character attributes of dataframes which are required to have them and for them to be unique to be considered properly formed. You can access them or modify them with the `attr` function, or more conveniently and safely with `rownames` and `rownames<-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can create `data.frame` with `row.names` from CSV file:

```
# Names in the first column
path_country <- read.table("C:/path_country.csv", row.names=1)
# Names in column "Country"
path_country <- read.table("C:/path_country.csv", row.names="Country", head=TRUE)
```

Note, that in second case you should specify `head=TRUE` in order to use columns' names.

Now `rownames(path_country)` should give you vector with rows' names, and `as.data.frame(patho.hclust.groups11)` nice result for export.

2) At any time you can specify rows' names for your `data.frame` with command:

```
rownames(path_country) <- names.vector
```

where `names.vector` is a vector with unique names of length equal to number of rows in `data.frame`. In your example:

```
rownames(patho.hclust.groups11) <- path_country$Country
```

Note, that if you are using first approach you don't need this command.